# VBA: Reset form control properties (e.g. size) to their original state

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls, ms-access-2010

### Edit:

> @Kostas K. correctly pointed out that I'm overthinking things and can just use conditional formatting to change and reset colour. However, my second, more general question still stands. Assume, for the sake of argument, that conditional formatting is not an option.

Let's say you make a textbox which changes colour under certain circumstances. For example:

```
If Me.txtTextbox.Value > [somevalue] Then
    Me.txtTextbox.BackColor = vbYellow
End If
```

We also want to reset it to the original colour. Easy:

```
If Me.txtTextbox.Value <= [somevalue] Then
    Me.txtTextbox.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
```

However, suppose we redesign the form so the textbox is blue. You now have to edit the VBA too, or the textbox will reset to the wrong colour. Changing .BackColor in VBA is not permanent: close and reopen the form, and the textbox is back to normal. **Is there a way, using VBA, to reset the background colour to its original state?**

<s>One option would be to save the background colour to a public variable, or to a control in the form header, and reset from there:</s>

```
If Me.txtTextbox.Value > [somevalue] Then
    publicvarTextboxCol = Me.txtTextbox.BackColor
    Me.txtTextbox.BackColor = vbYellow
End If
If Me.txtTextbox.Value <= [somevalue] Then
    Me.txtTextbox.BackColor = publicvarTextboxCol
End If
```

...but I can't believe there's not a simpler way.

**Is there a way to reset a control's properties (e.g. size) to their original values without closing and reopening the form?**

Comment: You don't need VBA for that, use conditional formatting.

Comment: In my defence, I originally wanted to do something else when the condition was met (namely wipe the textbox) then decided just to change the formatting, so my brain was locked in VBA mode.

Comment: We've all been there. :)

Comment: One useful option with each control is the 'Tag' property. It accepts text values. At start of the form you can save in it any original values you need as comma separated and you can restore them back whenever required (or you can save them in design mode) ;).
I usually use it to filter controls for batch operations to controls ;)

Comment: Certainly. Regardless of approach, requires saving the original values somewhere - VBA variables, table, tag property.